# Trying to use key listener but shape won't move

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, keylistener

I have added a keylistener to try and get a shape to move right when I press the right arrow key. But it isn't working. I don't really know how to use keylistner that well. Can someone help me.

This is the code:

```
package walkingman;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class WalkingMan extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 150, 150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Walking Man");
        frame.setSize(1080,720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        WalkingMan game = new WalkingMan();
        frame.add(game);

        while (true){
            game.repaint();
            game.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            x++;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you call the `game.keyPressed(e);` here? It will be fired while you pressed the key.

Comment: I've removed that and it still doesn't work @BahramdunAdil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code

1. You never add the `KeyListener` to the panel.
2. A `KeyListener` for a `JPanel` would only work if it is focusable & also focused.
3. Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.
4. Call `setVisible` at the end of the method.
5. Get rid of the whole while-loop, it'll only cause problems.
6. Use [`KeyBindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`s.

---

Fixed code without key bindings:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class WalkingMan extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // Overide paintComponent, not paint
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 150, 150);
    }

    public WalkingMan() { // Class Constructor
        setFocusable(true); // KeyListeners only work if the component is focusable
        addKeyListener(this); // Add the KeyListener implemented by this class to the instance
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Walking Man");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        WalkingMan game = new WalkingMan();
        frame.add(game);

        frame.setSize(1080, 720);
        frame.setVisible(true); // Call setVisible after adding the components

        game.requestFocusInWindow(); // Request focus for the panel
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new WalkingMan().createAndShowGUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x++;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: This works thanks very much. It would be really useful if you could explain what you've done to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Cutter What parts exactly don't you understand? I've updated my code with comments, I hope they help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Set frame well before it is displayed And remove the while loop which is still running.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Walking Man");
        frame.setSize(1080,720);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        WalkingMan game = new WalkingMan();
        frame.add(game);

        frame.setVisible(true);//Call visible method here

    }
```

Comment: You seem not to have defined any constructor for your class. How about defining one and call the JFrame and making it visible there

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not restructure your code in a much clear way like this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class WalkingMan  extends JFrame{
    EmilsKeyClass keyBoard = new EmilsKeyClass();

    public WalkingMan (){
        add(keyBoard,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        keyBoard.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 

                    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                        x++;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        keyBoard.setFocusable(true);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        WalkingMan  frame = new WalkingMan ();

        frame.setTitle("Walking Man");
        frame.setSize(1080,720);   
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public class EmilsKeyClass extends JPanel{
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        public EmilsKeyClass(){            
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            super.paint(g);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 150, 150);
            //your code
        }  
    }

}
```